# Which are the inbuilt modules responsible for System calls in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, system-calls, node-modules

Which are the inbuilt modules like child_process in Node.js which are responsible to make system calls?
I want to know each and every method in these module as well. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node uses a set of packages like 'child_process', 'fs' .... which are written in C / C++ which internally make system calls. And what system calls are you talking about ?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia I want to know only node.js function which is used to execute some unix commad. Btw thanks for your kind reply :)

Answer (score 2):

For only execute the command you can use the child_process module

```
1. spwan
2. exec
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html